# Improving my MYSQL queries

Tags: mysql

```
# Query_time: 0.007476  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 13463 
SELECT id,name FROM items 
WHERE items_approved = 1 AND item_name LIKE '%apple%' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

I just noticed I have lots of slow queries in my mysql-slow.log 
so I'm starting to optimize them one by one...

Let's start with this simple query:

```
SELECT id,name FROM items 
WHERE items_approved = 1 AND item_name LIKE '%red%' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

but the table contains 15K items so I need a better way to get 4 random items.
The items table has two indexes: one fulltext on name and one primary on id

in my e-commerce, the goal is basically to show 4 random items that have the word "red" in the name for each category (about 15 categories) anytime a user visit a page.

what's a better approach to this?

UPDATE

my.cnf is set like this

```
 log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
 long_query_time = 2
 log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined?

Comment: Less than 1 second is fine. You probably have your slow_queries set to 0. Try raising it to a more reasonable number so you can track true slow queries.

Comment: Less than 1 second is fine? What kind of logic is that?

Comment: The kind of logic that worries about queries that are more than 4 seconds?

Comment: so it seems is set for queries slower than 2 secs. I do have indexes on that tables. but maybe either i dont know how to use indexes or dont know exactly what they are...

Comment: But it's a ridiculous statement.

Comment: Don't you have to use specialized functions to take advantage of fulltext indexes?

Comment: @Francesco can you post the EXPLAIN PLAN for the query?

Comment: i don't know what EXPLAIN PLAN is...how do i do it?

Comment: also, I recently installed SOLR for my searches, so I'm not sure if I still need to have FULLTEXT on the item name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,name FROM items 
WHERE items_approved = 1 
  AND item_name LIKE '%red%' -- '% %' doesnt use index, change to FULL TEXT SEARCH
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 4;
```

Check MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

If you have full text index should try something like:

```
SELECT id,name FROM items 
WHERE items_approved = 1 
  AND MATCH(item_name) 
  AGAINST('red' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 4;
```